# LaTeX table sentences not going to the next line automatically and font sizes not the same as the rest of the document

Tags: tables

I have been trying to tabulate some data using latex but every time i put in a large sentence it doesn't go the next line automatically, but instead ti just extends the table as wide as the sentence is, in addition to that the font sizes in my table isn't the same as the rest of my document.

Here is my LaTeX table code:

```
    \begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{Input parameters for the rational method formula, Equation \ref{discharge}.}
\label{imput}
\begin{adjustbox}{width=1\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l}
\cline{1-2}
\textbf{Input Parameters} & \textbf{Description}  \\ \cline{1-2}
Coefficient of runoff & The coefficient of runoff accounts for the hydraulic behavior of the runoff as it flows over different types of surfaces in the drainage area. The coefficient for different surfaces can be obtained from Table \ref{c}   \\ \cline{1-2}
Rainfall Intensity & This parameter represents the amount of rainfall per a specified time. This can be obtained from rainfall intensity vs duration curves. However, In South Africa the rainfall intensity can be obtained from the software discussed in Topic [REF A CHAPTER]   \\ \cline{1-2}
\multirow{3}{*}{Time of Concentration} & This parameter represents the amount of time it would take the runoff from any point to get to a drainage outlet. Moreover, this parameter can go further in-detail as to consider the time of surface flow and time of flow in the drainage structure.  \\ \cline{2-2}
& The key factors that can affect this system is that the slope of the land and characteristics of the surface that the runoff will be flowing over.  \\ \cline{2-2}
& It is recommended that Equation \ref{tcs} should be used for the estimation of surface flow time. Moreover, Equation \ref{tcd} can be used to obtain the drainage flow time. \\ \cline{1-2}
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}
```

[This is how my table is looking now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHqgp.jpg)

Comment: never scale tables,  with adjustbox, resizebox, etc, the result will look horrible, you have specified `\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l}` where `l` means a single lne left aligned entry in each cell, to allow multi-line entries use `p{3cm}` instead of `l` or whatever width you want for the column

Comment: This is the meaning of saving a life, haha. Thank you mate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need have only two columns. Here is a code with `tabularx`, and a slightly different layout (no `\cline`s, replaced with a vertical spacing):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry} 
\usepackage{tabularx, ragged2e, caption, makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
    \centering\setcellgapes{3pt}\makegapedcells
    \caption{Input parameters for the rational method formula, Equation \ref{discharge}.}
    \label{imput}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{| >{\hsize=0.5\hsize\RaggedRight}X| >{\hsize=1.5\hsize\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X|}
        \hline
        \textbf{Input Parameters} & \textbf{Description} \\ \cline{1-2}
        Coefficient of runoff & The coefficient of runoff accounts for the hydraulic behavior of the runoff as it flows over different types of surfaces in the drainage area. The coefficient for different surfaces can be obtained from Table \ref{c} \\ \cline{1-2}
        Rainfall Intensity & This parameter represents the amount of rainfall per a specified time. This can be obtained from rainfall intensity vs duration curves. However, In South Africa the rainfall intensity can be obtained from the software discussed in Topic [REF A CHAPTER] \\ 
        \hline
        Time of Concentration & This parameter represents the amount of time it would take the runoff from any point to get to a drainage outlet. Moreover, this parameter can go further in-detail as to consider the time of surface flow and time of flow in the drainage structure. \\[2ex]
        & The key factors that can affect this system is that the slope of the land and characteristics of the surface that the runoff will be flowing over. \\[2ex]
        & It is recommended that Equation \ref{tcs} should be used for the estimation of surface flow time. Moreover, Equation \ref{tcd} can be used to obtain the drainage flow time. \\ 
        \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]